# RAD 9 upgrade causes publishing error on jaxws app

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-ws, rad, apt

I have a webapp with a web service in it and little else being converted from RAD 8 to RAD 9.  I go to publish this app, and I get the following warning.  Yet, the app does publish, although it needs a restart.  I created the web service and everything in RAD.  I am not running these tools manually.  I don't really understand what I am supposed to do with this error.

```
Publishing failed
deployFailure
Deploying eNotesApp
Deployment from com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.deployer.JAXWSDeployer had errors:  
Deployment from com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.deployer.JAXWSDeployer had errors:  
Deployment from com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.deployer.JAXWSDeployer had errors:  
Deployment from com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.deployer.JAXWSDeployer had errors:  
Errors occurred during wsgen.
Errors occurred during wsgen.
error: compilation failed, errors should have been reported
warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be
removed in the next major JDK release.  These features have been
superseded by javac and the standardized annotation processing API,
javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.  Users are
recommended to migrate to the annotation processing features of
javac; see the javac man page for more information.
Note:   ap round: 1
Problem encountered during annotation processing; 
see stacktrace below for more information.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalType(WebServiceVisitor.java:794)
at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalParameter(WebServiceVisitor.java:694)
at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalMethod(WebServiceVisitor.java:661)
at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.methodsAreLegal(WebServiceVisitor.java:611)
at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.isLegalImplementation(WebServiceVisitor.java:529)
at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.shouldProcessWebService(WebServiceVisitor.java:332)
at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.visitClassDeclaration(WebServiceVisitor.java:123)
at com.sun.tools.apt.mirror.declaration.ClassDeclarationImpl.accept(ClassDeclarationImpl.java:125)
at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.buildModel(WebServiceAP.java:329)
at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.process(WebServiceAP.java:270)
at com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessors$CompositeAnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessors.java:83)
at com.sun.tools.apt.comp.Apt.main(Apt.java:492)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.AptJavaCompiler.compile(AptJavaCompiler.java:282)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:1139)
at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:1001)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Main.java:125)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:115)
at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:97)
at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.buildModel(WsgenTool.java:223)
at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.run(WsgenTool.java:123)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.jws22.v85.command.AbstractWsGenCommand.execute(AbstractWsGenCommand.java:134)
at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.emitter.command.WebServiceAPCommand.execute(WebServiceAPCommand.java:50)
at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.deployer.JAXWSWebServiceAPInvoker.executeWSAPForProject(JAXWSWebServiceAPInvoker.java:141)
at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.deployer.JAXWSDeployer.execute(JAXWSDeployer.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.deploy.J2EEDeployOperation.deploy(J2EEDeployOperation.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.deploy.J2EEDeployOperation.execute(J2EEDeployOperation.java:113)
at com.ibm.etools.server.task.ejbdeploy.internal.JEEDeployPublisher.execute(JEEDeployPublisher.java:207)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Publisher.execute(Publisher.java:176)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.executePublishers(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:1277)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:960)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3153)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Deployment from com.ibm.ast.ws.deployer.WSDeployer completed successfully
OK
OK
OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bizarrely, this seems to be the result of some leftover artifacts from when I was working with policy sets in RAD 8.  The result was that the META-INF directory had some files to describe the policy sets (though they were set to inoccuous settings).  Once removed, the warning went away.  Evidently something about these RAD 8 generated files triggered the behavior, even though they did not do so in RAD 8.